# When an image is picked from the IOS Gallery it rotates when it is placed..but only on one device - Xcode

Tags: ios, rotation

OK , so this is weird and after extensive searching I cant find an answer.

I have an app that picks a photo from the photo gallery and places it into a view in the first view controller this then sends it to the second view controller and shows the image... simple enough

On my own device when I run the APP it works OK , when I install the device on my phone as an IPA it works ok...**BUT**

When I send the app to test to a friend of mine , it always **'ROTATES'** the image 90 degrees..when it is placed in the second view controller

When he picks the image from his gallery it is aligned correctly , he can even take a photo  , store it , and use it within the first view controller but when sent to the second , it **ROTATES**...BUT it still rotates 90 degrees..

ANY THOUGHTS ???